# import error in python hmmlearn

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I am trying to install python hmmlearn library to build continuous HMM. I have installed all the dependencies and the hmmlearn library from GitHub. The installation completes successfully.

```
...
Processing dependencies for hmmlearn==0.2.1
Searching for scikit-learn==0.18.1
Best match: scikit-learn 0.18.1
Adding scikit-learn 0.18.1 to easy-install.pth file
Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Finished processing dependencies for hmmlearn==0.2.1
```

But in python, when I try to import GaussianHMM using

```
from hmmlearn.hmm import GaussianHMM
```

it gives some import error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "hmmlearn/hmm.py", line 22, in <module>
 from .base import _BaseHMM
 File "hmmlearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
 from . import _hmmc
 ImportError: cannot import name _hmmc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in hmmlearn/setup.py which doesn't list utils as a submodule.

Add this line to setup.py `config.add_subpackage("utils")`

```
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
         include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
         libraries=libraries,
     )
-
+    config.add_subpackage("utils")
     return config

 if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this

**config.add_subpackage("utils")**

inside setup.py . My setup.py file does not have 

**

    **@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
             include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
             libraries=libraries,
         )**

**

when I add above command before  if __name__ == '__main__': I recieve the error message that config is like valid command name.